# csfml wait event

Tags: sfml, c

I would like to spawn a separate thread to deal with inputs using c and sfml.
I made a prototype that waits for input in main() and it works fine.
I made a prototype that spawns a new thread and waits for input and no input is received.

Here is the second prototype:
http://pastebin.com/S4EmPTBL

Can I have some help to get this going?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [annother thread](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10642.msg73476#msg73476)

"As for the problem, you'll have to handle the events in the same thread as you've created the window - at least that's the case in SFML 2" -eXpl0it3r